# flutter listview inside pageview

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to place a List view inside a page view so that I can swipe horizontally between pages and scroll vertically on each page (because is a list view). However, there is the following problem.

```
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.

Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PageView PageView:file:///C:/Users/MEL/Desktop/Universidad/Desarrollo%20Movil/weather/lib/View/home.dart:46:30
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      RenderViewport.computeDryLayout.<anonymous closure>
```

The code is the following

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:weather/Data/Remote/weather_client.dart';
import 'package:weather/View/Widgets/home_widgets.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      top: false,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext ctx, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          return Scaffold(
            extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
            appBar: AppBar(
              elevation: 0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              leading: IconButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  var client =
                      OpenWeatherWapClient('e716074c196d8c560f0b61f6ea416f30');
                  client.fetchWeatherCity('Tokyo');
                },
                icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.search),
              ),
            ),
            body: Stack(
              children: [
                Image.asset('Assets/night.jpg',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    height: double.infinity,
                    width: double.infinity),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.175,
                    ),
                    PageView.builder(
                        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => WeatherCityItem(constraints: constraints)),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The file where

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class WeatherStatisticItem extends StatefulWidget {
  var constraints;

  WeatherStatisticItem({Key? key, this.constraints}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<WeatherStatisticItem> createState() => _WeatherStatisticItemState();
}

class _WeatherStatisticItemState extends State<WeatherStatisticItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 10),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        CupertinoIcons.thermometer,
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.08),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "HUMIDITY",
                        style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                            fontSize: widget.constraints.maxWidth * 0.035,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                            letterSpacing: 0.001,
                            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.35)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      "11°",
                      style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                          fontSize: widget.constraints.maxWidth * 0.075,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                          letterSpacing: 0.001,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Text(
                "Simlar to the actual temperature",
                style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                    fontSize: widget.constraints.maxWidth * 0.04,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                    letterSpacing: 0.001,
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.white10),
            color: Colors.black54.withOpacity(0.25),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WeatherCityItem extends StatelessWidget {
  var constraints;
  WeatherCityItem({Key? key, this.constraints}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: 0, horizontal: 20),

        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  "Bogotá",
                  style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                      fontSize: constraints.maxWidth * 0.11,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "11°",
                style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                    fontSize: constraints.maxWidth * 0.175,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                    letterSpacing: 0.001,
                    color: Colors.white),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Icon(CupertinoIcons.clock,
                      color: Colors.white),
                  Container(
                    width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.0175,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "11:18 pm",
                    style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                        fontSize: constraints.maxWidth * 0.05,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                        letterSpacing: 0.001,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.075,
              )
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 15, horizontal: 10),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Align(
                  child: Text(
                    "Weather report",
                    style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                        fontSize: constraints.maxWidth * 0.055,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        letterSpacing: 0.001,
                        color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                ),
                const Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Divider(
                    color: Colors.white54,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut iaculis risus orci, non consequat nulla pulvinar",
                  style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                      fontSize: constraints.maxWidth * 0.04,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      letterSpacing: 0.001,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.white10),
              color: Colors.black54.withOpacity(0.25),
              borderRadius:
              BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              WeatherStatisticItem(constraints: constraints),
              WeatherStatisticItem(constraints: constraints),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              WeatherStatisticItem(constraints: constraints),
              WeatherStatisticItem(constraints: constraints),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              WeatherStatisticItem(constraints: constraints),
              WeatherStatisticItem(constraints: constraints),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

I've made some research on the internet and its workaround appears to be to add a fixed size box to the list view, this doesn't work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ur `Stack`, u should wrap an `Expanded` to `ListView`, or it don't know  its height.

By the way, if u need a background image, u can wrap a `Container` to ur `Column` and set its
decoration->image.
And then u can remove ur `Stack`.

Some code

```dart
body: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('Assets/night.jpg')),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.175,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: PageView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => WeatherCityItem(constraints: constraints),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Dont forget to remove `Expanded` in ur `WeatherCityItem`.
Widget in `PageView`, default max width, which in ur case is screenWidth.